# copy columns between two tables without inserting new rows

Tags: mysql

table1 - columns:
id,
date,

table2 - columns:
id,
date,
img,
auth,
moder,
tags,
visits

table1 - 1200 rows
table2 - 1000 rows

I want to copy missing columns from table2 to table1 (img, auth, moder, tags, visits).

regardless of values (this are all test data, doesn't matter what value is on a certain row).

I tried firstly to create missing columns in table1 and then:

```
insert into table1 (img, auth, moder, tags, visits) select img, auth, moder, tags, visits from table2;
```

But this inserts new rows into table1. I don't want new rows - just add new columns having data from table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you want here is an *update*, not an insert, since you don't actually want to add new records, just modify ones which already exist.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date = t2.date
SET
    t1.img = t2.img,
    t1.auth = t2.auth,
    t1.moder = t2.moder,
    t1.tags = t2.tags,
    t1.visits = t2.visits;
```

Comment: why `JOIN ON t1.id = t2.id and...` this is not a must. t1.id could be any id and t2.id could be any id

Comment: @qadenza If there is no way to relate a record from one table to the other table, then there is no way to do a meaningful update.

Comment: @qadenza surely you only want to copy the data from table2 that has the same id and date value as the row in table1? that is what the join condition is for...

Comment: is there a query like this - `copy columns (...) from t2 to t1`?

Comment: That is a meaningless thing, because there is no inherent order in SQL tables.  The only order is the one you impose using things like keys.

Answer (score 1):

use update

```
update table1 
join table2 on table1.id=table2.id and table1.date=table2.date
set  tabl1.img=tabl2.img, table1.auth=table2.auth, table1.moder=table1.moder,
table1.tags=table2,tags, table1.visits=table2.visits
```